# Multilinear Interpolation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, interpolation

Suppose I have a multilinear map $\Gamma(u,v)$ satisfying
\begin{align}
 \big\| \Gamma(u,v)\big\|_{L^2} &\leq \big\| u\big\|_{L^2} \big\| v\big\|_{L^2} \\
\big\| \Gamma(u,v)\big\|_{L^\infty} &\leq \big\| u\big\|_{L^\infty} \big\| v\big\|_{L^\infty}
\end{align}
I would like to show that
\begin{align}
 \big\| \Gamma(u,v)\big\|_{L^p} &\leq \big\| u\big\|_{L^p} \big\| v\big\|_{L^p}
\end{align}
for all $p\in (2,\infty)$. I realize this looks like a multilinear Riesz-Thorin interpolation type theorem, but am having trouble finding showing this/reference. Thanks.

Comment: The theorems in Section 4.4 of Bergh-Lofstrom http://www.math.chalmers.se/~bergh/Interpolation.pdf should probably do the trick (though one may have to unpack their notation a bit, as they work in a quite general context).  Alternatively, one can simply repeat the proof of the classical Riesz-Thorin theorem.

Comment: It seems like paragraph 10.1 on Calderon's paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm24/sm24110.pdf also contains what you are looking for.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the help.